# Class method calling issue for UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, uiimage

I have to call a `Class method` from a class to another class and Actually into the class method I have to pass the `UIImage`.
so I have Created a `NSObject` and calling it in the `Viewcontroller` buttons

how to call the `UIImageView` and where ..please check the code where I am getting wrong..

what changes do i require in method to call image

**Zaction.h**

```
@interface ZAction : NSObject

@property (retain) NSString *title;
@property (assign) id <NSObject> target;
@property (assign) SEL action;
@property (retain) id <NSObject> object;
@property(retain) UIImageView *image;

+ (ZAction *)actionWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle target:(id)aTarget action:(SEL)aAction object:(id)aObject image:(UIImageView *)Aimage;;
```

**ZAction.m**

```
@implementation ZAction

@synthesize title;
@synthesize target;
@synthesize action;
@synthesize object,image;

 + (ZAction *)actionWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle target:(id)aTarget action:(SEL)aAction object:(id)aObject image:(UIImageView *)Aimage;
{
    ZAction *actionObject = [[[ZAction alloc] init] autorelease];
    actionObject.title = aTitle;
    actionObject.target = aTarget;
    actionObject.action = aAction;
    actionObject.object = aObject;
    actionObject.image=Aimage;
    return actionObject;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 #import "Zaction.h"
- (IBAction)test4Action:(id)sender
{
    UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    ZAction *destroy = [ZAction actionWithTitle:@"Clear" target:self action:@selector(colorAction:) object:[UIColor clearColor] image:image1];
    ZAction *sec = [ZAction actionWithTitle:@"Unclear" target:self action:@selector(colorAction:) object:[UIColor clearColor] image:image1];
    image1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:image1];


   ZActionSheet *sheet = [[[ZActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" cancelAction:nil destructiveAction:destroy
                otherActions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:option1,  nil]] autorelease];
    sheet.identifier = @"test4";
    [sheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to call the UIImageView"?

Comment: means I need to get image for the `ZAction *destroy` and `ZAction *sec` ..what changes are method to get images

Comment: UIImage *yourImage = destroy.image.image;

Comment: Yeah the `image` property is badly named and should be `imageView`.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ya but images not displaying...whether the class method is correct?? and image will be get called in the `test4Action` in the same way??

Comment: @trojanfoe didnt get you ..what should i do

Comment: You need to ask a more coherent question! What does "call the image" mean?

Comment: like I need a UIActionsheet buttons for them I have created a Class methods and In class methods I want image , for UIActionSheet Buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some serious issues:

- Your UIImageView image1 is initialized with a CGRectZero frame - maybe it's not displayed because the frame is (0,0,0,0)? Tr giving it a real size, e.g. the image's size.
- Next to that your ZAction objects sec and destroy will be gone at the end of the test4Action method, as they are autoreleased and not retained anywhere.
- You also have some unnecessary semi-colons in your code - especially the one behind the method implementation of actionWithTitle I would get rid of, you can get some nasty errors with misplaced semicolons (like after an if() statement ...).
- Please also work on your coding style (naming of variables in particular - c language keywords make no good attribute names ('object' in your action class), Aimage should be aImageView)

Comment: ok thanks.. but I was taking `CGRectZero` Frame beacause this image would be on the UIActionSheet Button..I cant define the frame size into that ,..that y i used it `CGRectZero` ...and if i give the Frame size ..there would be no use of the `Class method ` of `image:(UIImageView *)Aimage` as all the things i will define into - `(IBAction)test4Action:(id)sender` needed for the image like..(below)

Comment: `UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)]; image1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:image1]`